# Simpson's Paradox for $R^2$

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, statistics, optimization, linear-regression

I've been reading about [Simpson's Paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simpson%27s_paradox) and I understand how if you fit a regression on a per-group basis versus on the entire set, the coefficients in each group can be drastically different from coefficients on the global set because of confounding variables. However, one thought I had was whether such a principle would hold for an accuracy metric. For instance, if I run a linear model on the entire set with an $R^2 >0$, is it possible to split the dataset into two groups $A,B$ such that $R^2_A < 0$ **and** $R^2_B < 0$?

Comment: Can you define your terms (or link to definitions)? What is an accuracy metric? What is $R^2$?

Comment: How can you have a square less than $0$?

Comment: If you are asking about the sign of the correlation (not squared), then yes - see the [first chart](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/47/Simpson%27s_paradox_continuous.svg/390px-Simpson%27s_paradox_continuous.svg.png) in the Wikipedia article and reverse it